# Impact or effect

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I am trying to translate a sentence in to English and I'm wondering if I can use impact and effect alternatively in this sentense:

> The comparison between the ______of wet and dry dressing on burn wound healing.

Which one is better to use in the gap **impact** or **effect**?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: "*Effect*".

"*Impact*" generally indicates the powerful effect of something new or the power.

> The president's decision had an *impact* on young people.
>
> The *impact* of the crash totally destroyed the car.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a matter of opinion about style. Using **impact** to mean **effect strongly** is common in modern American speech. Some people object to the usage: do we really want impacts on wounds?

Without taking a stand generally, it seems to me a comparison warrants **effect** because the difference in effectiveness may be small or even negligible.